# Bundle of important softwares

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, programming

Is there any bundle of softwares to download in a package for free?
I want software for everyday use and for general programming development.

**Edit**
Editor and other required programs to run PHP, C, C++, Java.
A music & video player, an image editor.

Comment: This is a very generic question, there are hundreds of thousand's of opinions on what *everyday use* actually, is, so no, there would not be. Not to mention *General programming* is the same boat, you will have a different IDE from php than java...

Comment: Also, you would get a lot more hits if you tagged your question properly (e.g. programming, software)

Comment: There isn't really a single package containing everything although it's possible to create on by using metapackages (which involves creating an own package). What's wrong with `sudo apt-get install php5 build-essential openjdk-6-jdk vlc gimp`? Unlike windows where you've to download each installer one by one, you can use package management to install your "bundle". As previously shown, this can consist of one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't download all of those in one package for Ubuntu. The music and video player comes with the OS, the image editor is GIMP and has to be downloaded separately. The IDEs have to be downloaded separately unless you order the DVD installation of Ubuntu which includes a lot more software.